# Advantages of running a CI environment on JavaScript projects

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration

I have been recently looking at installing either team city or Jenkins as a CI solution. I am quite aware of the advantages it can bring to my teams c++ projects with nightly builds to test if anything checked into git has broken the project or dependent projects. Also as a way of building and releasing software.

However I know people use it on JavaScript projects. These cannot be built as such and can only really be tested at runtime. So what is the real advantage of using a CI solution on a JavaScript project comprising of back end and web front end code.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

While the build and test stages are typically looked at as 2 completely different CI steps they're fundamentally just verifications (OK, with a dependency in between them) which would have to ALL pass for the CI iteration to be considered successful.

When talking about breakages people typically refer to build failures, but fundamentally there is no difference from the usability prospective between an artifact missing because it failed to build and an artifact successfully built but DOA/unusable from the testing prospective - none of them can be shipped, they're equally blocking the larger team's development/testing activities, etc.

So if there is nothing to build for your particular context just skip that step (or make it an always BUILD SUCCESS bypass if the CI system doesn't support a missing build step).

You'd still get all the advantages of using the CI methodology/verification in your development process.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of CI is to detect problems early instead of waiting to find them at runtime. JavaScript should not be exempt from this process especially if you have a lot of it. Running static analysis, e.g., [jslint/jshint](http://jshint.com/) and unit tests can and will save you a lot of headache in the long run. My team specifically uses [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) as our testing framework and we have a well defined set of JSLint rules. If any test fails or any rule is broken the code cannot be checked-in. In addition, we require code reviews for all our code (including JS). This, I belive, is the most valuable step in our CI process.